# Передача данных в background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Изучаю создание расширений для Google Chrome.

Как понял из документации, есть 2 скрипта: *background.js*, который выполняется в тени, и *front.js*, который работает с DOM страницы.

Мне нужно как-то из *front* послать в *backround* событие, чтобы там выполнилась функция и передала ответ обратно.

Например, по клику по какому-нибудь тегу запустилась функция в *background.js*.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы отправить сообщение с *front* (или как чаще ее называют - *content*) доступен метод `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message, callback)` ([документация](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage)), где `message` - непосредственно само сообщение, `callback` - функция, в которую будет передан ответ от *background*, если таковой имеется (дополнительные параметры в документации).

Чтобы получить сообщение на *background* (или *event*) существует `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(callback)` ([документация](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)), где `callback` - функция-обработчик сообщения. Она прининимает аргументы `message`, `sender` и `sendResponse`, где `message` - само сообщение, `sender` - информация об отправителе сообщения (например информация о вкладке, с которой отправили сообщение) и `sendResponse` - функция, которую нужно вызвать, если необходимо отправить ответ обратно на *front*.

Таким образом, чтобы отправить сообщение по клику и получить ответ:

```
// front.js
document.addEventListener('click', function () {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('Hello, background', function (response) {
        console.log(response); // 'Hi front!'
    });
}, false);

// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(message); // 'Hello background'
    sendResponse('Hi front!');
});
```

Пространство `chrome.runtime` используется с Chrome 26+, до этой версии использовалось `chrome.extension`. (т.е. `chrome.extension.sendMessage` и `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener`).

Comment: А чтобы послать с background на front, нужно использовать  те же самые функции?

Comment: Для отправки  - [chrome.tabs.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage). [Тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14245504/1573638) есть пример отправки сообщения на текущую активную вкладку. Для получения сообщения все то же самое.